# jQuery: set a jQuery object as a [html] content

Tags: jquery

Is there a shortcut for:

```
var child = $('<span>error message</span>');
$('#parent').html(child.html());
```

or, the same

```
var child = $('<span>error message</span>');
$('#parent').empty().append(child);
```

**EDIT**: above example won't work if I try to assign same child to multiple parents, my `child` object can only belong to a single parent (which is not what I wanted in my case).

I do realize I could do:

```
$('#parent').html('<span>error message</span>');
```

but I want to reuse `child` object.
**EDIT**: again, this won't work, since `child` is a DOM object and can only be placed under at most one parent at any time.

I am looking for something like:

```
var child = $('<span>error message</span>');
$('#parent').content(child);
```

Comment: What kind of shortcut? The first example looks as short as it could be to my eyes.

Comment: If you want to reuse the `child` object then you'll need to keep a reference to it so no, there is no shorter way than you're already doing

Comment: both `.empty().append(...)` and `.html(child.html())` are too verbose (exhibit unnecessary details superfluous to my intentions). Plus `.html(child.html())` feels suboptimal (reconstruct-deconstruct HTML)

Comment: @Felix Kling: what I am trying to do is precisely this: 'set content of an element'. Neither of my examples concisely state that (too much details). If there is not built-in jQuery method for that, I will use `empty().append()`.

Comment: using `html(content)` on an element will simply overwrite anything that was in there in the first place, no need to use empty

Comment: @Tules: You are right, I think it is also possible to pass a jQuery object to `.html`. But it is not described in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var child = $('<span>error message</span>').attr({ 'class' : 'error-message'});
$('#parent').html(child.clone());
```

notice that you have to `clone()` `child` unless you want to actually move child from its previous parent.

credits to both [Tules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555116/tules) and [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)

Answer (score 2):

You can always wrap functionality in a plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.setContent = function(content) {
        return this.empty().append(content);
    };
}(jQuery));

$('#parent').setContent(child);
```

Also if you want to reuse an existing jQuery object, you probably have to use `.clone()` if you want to insert it later somewhere else.

Comment: you missed `$.each()` on `this`. other than that this would pretty-up my code, but the original question was `is there a shortcut` not a `how can I pretty this up`. Valid solution though. +1

Comment: @user93422: Why should I need `each`?

Comment: "I need to make this code shorter" "you could always write a new plugin!" hmmm. Would that give you a different result than `$('#parent').html(child);`?

Comment: @Tules: Actually not... but as I was saying, passing a DOM element is not described in the documentation so we don't know whether this is an intended feature or not. One could also argue that `setContent` is more expressive than `html`.

Comment: if content is a jquery object (in my example it is a DOM element) thin it is not possible to assign it to multiple parents. I.e. my original examples are correct but invalid. I have to copy my object by using `.html()` after all.

Comment: @user93422: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QaU5G/ and as I said, you might have to use `.clone()` somewhere in the process but in this case appending to multiple elements works as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
var child = '<span>error message</span>';
$('#parent').html(child);
```

is the shortest you are possibly gonna get, how short does  it really need to be? lol

Comment: I would prefer to have child pre-built, but a valid solution nevertheless. +1

Comment: in that case ur first example really is the shortest ur gonna get

Comment: see my edits. child as a DOM object can not be reused, for that reason your answer is the correct one. I would replace `child = '...'` with `child = $(...).html()` for the convenience of being able to specify attributes using `.attr()`.

Comment: ...and I'm wrong again. `.html()` will give me content of the `child` DOM element, not an 'outerHtml'. So your solution is pretty much as good as I can get without plugins/extensions.

Comment: using `.clone()` on the child would allow to reuse a child pre-built as a DOM element.

Answer (score -1):

you could try something like

```
      var child = $('#parent').html('<span>error message</span>').children('span:eq(0)');
```

Ive not tried it myself. To be honest your first example seems pretty good to me.

Comment: Right... and I'm just saying that your code is not correct. Not trying is not an excuse for posting erroneous code imo, especially when it contains syntax errors.